# Erlang repetition string in string

Tags: erlang

I have a string:

> "abc abc abc abc"

How do I calculate the number of "abc" repetitions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for practical and efficient implementation which will scale well for even longer substrings you can use `binary:matches/2,3` which is using [Boyer–Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) (and [Aho-Corasic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) for multiple substrings). It obviously works only for ASCII or Latin1 strings.

```erlang
repeats(L, S) -> length(binary:matches(list_to_binary(L), list_to_binary(S))).
```

If it is for education purposes, you can write your own less efficient version for lists of any kind. If you know substring in compile time you can use very simple and not so much bad in performance:

```erlang
-define(SUBSTR, "abc").

repeats(L) -> repeats(L, 0).

repeats(?SUBSTR ++ L, N) -> repeats(L, N+1);
repeats([_|L]       , N) -> repeats(L, N);
repeats([]          , N) -> N.
```

If you don't know substring you can write a little bit more complicated and less efficient

```erlang
repeats(L, S) -> repeats(L, S, 0).

repeats([], _, N) -> N;
repeats(L, S, N) ->
    case prefix(L, S) of
        {found, L2} -> repeats( L2,   S, N+1);
        nope        -> repeats(tl(L), S, N)
    end.

prefix([H|T], [H|S]) -> prefix(T, S);
prefix( L,    [   ]) -> {found, L};
prefix( _,     _   ) -> nope.
```

And you, of course, can try write some more sophisticated variant as simplified Boyer–Moore for lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
1> F = fun 
  F([],_,_,N) -> N; 
  F(L,P,S,N) -> 
    case string:sub_string(L,1,S) == P of 
      true -> F(tl(string:sub_string(L,S,length(L))),P,S,N+1);
      _ -> F(tl(L),P,S,N)
    end
  end.
  #Fun<erl_eval.28.106461118>
2> Find = fun(L,P) -> F(L,P,length(P),0) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.106461118>
3> Find("abc abc abc abc","abc").
4
4>
```

this works if defined in a module, or in the shell but only with the R17.

Answer (score 0):

```
 length(lists:filter(fun(X) -> X=="abc" end,  string:tokens("abc abc abc abc", " "))).
```